# How to apply wavelet filter to MRI nifti images?

Tags: python-2.7

I need to denoise nifti images using wavelet transform. I did it in MATLAB but I should write the code for my project in Python. I am new to Python.

Comment: What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Comment: I tried Pywavelet but I just can do transform on an array and I cannot save it in nifti. I am using vtk to read and write nifti.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a neuroimaging community of practice that lives at http://nipy.org.  In particular, they have a library called NiBabel (see their [introduction](https://nipy.org/nibabel/) and [github](https://github.com/nipy/nibabel)) for reading nifti and other formats (this will replace MATLAB's `niftiread`).  You may also be interested in the [PyWavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which can replace basic parts of the MATLAB wavelet toolbox.  The [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library is probably the most up to date image editing/processing library for Python, but as far as I'm aware wavelets isn't something covered there.

Is that enough to get you started?  A basic discussion of how Python packages work seems beyond the scope of this question, but you can do some reading at https://pypi.org/help/ if you are completely lost.

Comment: Thank you very much